# select "step" records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table

```
  grp |   ind |   val
----------------------
    a |     1 |     1
    a |     2 |     1
    a |     3 |     1
    a |     4 |     2
    a |     5 |     2
    a |     6 |     4
    a |     7 |     2
    b |     1 |     1
    b |     2 |     1
    b |     3 |     1
    b |     4 |     3
    b |     5 |     3
    b |     6 |     4
```

I need to select the following:

```
  grp |   ind |   val
----------------------
    a |     1 |     1
    a |     4 |     2
    a |     6 |     4
    a |     7 |     2
    b |     1 |     1
    b |     4 |     3
    b |     6 |     4
```

That is for each 'grp', each record where the 'val' is different to the proceeding 'val' (ordered by 'index') So each record where the 'value' "steps".

what would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

thanks.

Here is a script to create the test case:

```
create temp table test_table
(
    grp character varying,
    ind numeric,
    val numeric
);
insert into test_table values
    ('a', 1 , 1),
    ('a', 2 , 1),
    ('a', 3 , 1),
    ('a', 4 , 2),
    ('a', 5 , 2),
    ('a', 6 , 4),
    ('a', 7 , 2),
    ('b', 1 , 1),
    ('b', 2 , 1),
    ('b', 3 , 1),
    ('b', 4 , 3),
    ('b', 5 , 3),
    ('b', 6 , 4);
```

Comment: "group" and "index" both are keywords in SQL. Better avoid them as table or column names.

Comment: That's better, But I already invented my own table and columns names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select grp,
       ind,
       val
from (
   select grp, 
          ind, 
          val,
          lag(val,1,0::numeric) over (partition by grp order by ind) - val as diff
   from test_table
) t
where diff <> 0;
```

Comment: Lag() is cleaner than my self-join.

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE ztable
        ( zgroup CHAR(1)
        , zindex int
        , zvalue INTEGER
        );
INSERT INTO ztable(zgroup,zindex,zvalue) VALUES
    ('a',     1,      1)
    ,('a',     2,      1)
    ,('a',     3,      1)
    ,('a',     4,      2)
    ,('a',     5,      2)
    ,('a',     6,      4)
    ,('b',     1,      1)
    ,('b',     2,      1)
    ,('b',     3,      1)
    ,('b',     4,      3)
    ,('b',     5,      3)
    ,('b',     6,      4)
        ;

WITH agg AS (
        SELECT zgroup
        , zindex
        , zvalue
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zgroup ORDER BY zindex) AS zrank
        FROM ztable
        )
SELECT t1.zgroup,t1.zindex,t1.zvalue
FROM agg t1
LEFT JOIN agg t0 ON t0.zgroup = t1.zgroup AND 1+t0.zrank = t1.zrank
WHERE t0.zvalue <> t1.zvalue OR t0.zrank IS NULL
        ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i figured i would need to use sliding windows (partition) however when i run your example the result is all rows returned (ie the full table). does it actually work for you?

Comment: The lag() thing by @a_horse_with_no_name above is more elegant.

Comment: Try what? I tested my own script.

Answer (score 1):

```
select group,min(index) as index,value from table
group by group,value
```

Comment: that actually works fine .. for how i described the problem .. allow me to change the problem!! sorry i didn't include the case which makes this difficult, which is if the value decreases after it increases, i need to capture both the increase and the decrease. please see edit for more details, thanks for your answer and sorry to be confusing!

Comment: i gave you an vote for being correct. i still need help though so leaving this open...

Comment: It is *not* correct; it only works if value is unique or ascending wrt "index". Try adding records with index 7 and value 2 (for both a and b)to see what I mean.

Comment: @wildplasser .. it was correct at the time, i edited the question to make it incorrect (apologies again) - i had mis-described my problem.